# Codeigniter index parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter, indexing

This is not the only controller in the folder. I already deleted index.php.
but once i add this part of a function for a shopping cart

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Product extends CI_Controller 
{

  public function index($index = 0)
  {
      $data['listProduct'] = $this->mproduct->findAll();
      $this->load->view('template/header.php', $data);
      $this->load->view('index', $data);
  }
}
```

it gives me this error

Message: Undefined property: Product::$mproduct

Filename: controllers/product.php

Line Number: 7

here is my model

```
<?php

class MProduct extends CI_Model
{
    function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
    }

function findAll()
{
    return $this->db->get('product')->result();
}



    function find($id)
       {
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            return $this->db->get('product')->row();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the model first before calling it.

**Also the first letter should be capitalized with rest of the name should be in lowercase.**

> Class names must have the first letter capitalized with the rest of
>   the name lowercase. Make sure your class extends the base Model class.

[Refer](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html)

Add this:

```
$this->load->model ( 'Mproduct' );
$data['listProduct'] = $this->Mproduct->findAll();
```

Full code :

**Controller : controllers/Product.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Product extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{

    $this->load->model ( 'Mproduct' );
    $data['listProduct'] = $this->Mproduct->findAll();
    $this->load->view('template/header.php', $data);
    $this->load->view('index', $data);
}

}
```

**Model : models/Mproduct.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Mproduct extends CI_Model {

    function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
    }

function findAll()
{
    echo 'model';
}



    function find($id)
       {
            echo 'model';
        }
}
```